# What are canonical examples of parallel computation?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I am writing a paper to test a new application that will demonstrate the benefits of parallelized computation (compared to the traditional serialized version of this application).  I want to use the [canonical examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical#Computer_science) for parallel computation in my paper.

My first example is [the parallel computation of **pi**](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/parallel_comp/#ExamplesPI).  I would ideally like an example where each iteration is very time consuming (because of the additional overhead associated with parallelizing); my first thought is a Bayesian simulation with MCMC and Gibbs sampling.

What other problems are typically discussed in this context?  What are good examples of large [embarassingly parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) problems?

Comment: The wikipedia article you give contains a set of examples. What's wrong with them?

Comment: They're fine, although I don't think that they would be considered as the "standard set of examples" (e.g. the pi example isn't included there).  I don't just want any examples: I want the most famous examples.

Comment: @Shane: So why did you ask for "good examples" in the last sentence? Good ones may not always be famous.

Comment: @Jon: Fair point; that's why I included "canonical" in the title, which should imply famous/important.

Comment: What makes you think there are any canonical examples?

Comment: @David: The fact that this is a big area of research and making comparisons between methods requires some amount of standardization.  Research papers often use the same examples (e.g. the iris dataset for classification problems).

Answer (score 6):

just a few more -

- Multiplying matrices
- Inverting matrices
- [FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fft)
- String matching
- Rendering 3d scenes (via scan line conversion or ray tracing)

Answer (score 5):

One example I've used in the past of an embarrassingly parallel problem is visualizing the mandelbrot set. Each pixel can be computed independently.

Conway's Life is interesting as well, in that each value of the "next" board can be computed independently, but will depend on the relevant bits of the "current" board being done already.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest that **canonical examples of parallel computation** and **embarassingly parallel problems** are, if not completely, then nearly, disjoint sets.  To put it another way, people working in parallel computation aren't terribly excited about embarassingly parallel problems; we call them that because we'd be embarassed to be working on them.

I'd be looking, if I were you, at these (a not entirely original list):

- linear algebra on large dense matrices, both direct and iterative approaches;
- linear algebra on huge sparse matrices
- branch and bound approaches to linear programming (and related) problems;
- sequence matching for bioinformatics (outside my field, I may have mis-expressed this);
- continuos optimisation.

I expect there are many more.

**EDIT:** You may be interested in [this list of problems](http://www.prace-project.eu/news/prace-benchmark-suite-finalised) which have been selected for benchmarking the next generation of European (academic) supercomputers.  It will give you some idea of where that niche is heading.

Comment: +1 Thanks for this list.  I think "embarassingly" really implies things that are easily split up (ie. there are no dependencies between iterations), not that they are embarassing problems in and of themselves.

Comment: @Shane: I beg to differ, they are called embarassing because those of us working in parallel computing would be embarassed to be working on such easy problems; even worse, working on and making mistakes on.  It may be that they are so easy to parallelise because there are no dependencies between tasks but that's a different matter.

Comment: +1 for the link to the PRACE Benchmark Suite.  For the same reason, I would also add the SpecMPI benchmarks:   http://www.spec.org/mpi/

Answer (score 4):

Molecular dynamics simluations allow you to change the size of the problem until your computer resources are exhausted (i.e. 256 particles vs. 256,000,000 particles).  Its truly a "canonical" example if you run the MD simulations under NVT conditions ;-)

Answer (score 2):

My favorite example is monte carlo simulation.

Answer (score 1):

Word counting seems to be the canonical example for MapReduce.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce#Example

Answer (score 1):

Finding collisions in hash functions using Paul C. van Oorschot and Michael J. Weiner's [method](http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~paulv/papers/acmccs94.pdf) (PDF) comes up often in various cryptographic settings.

Answer (score 1):

I used the Mandelbrot set demo to explain to my mom what parallel programming is about : http://www.ateji.com/px/demo.html

All the examples you mentions are mostly heavy data-parallel codes. You'll probably want to mention also task-oriented codes, such as servers responding to many requests in parallel, and data-flow or stream programming examples (MapReduce is a good representative of this class).